# Retrieve and execute example code from an R package function as a codeblock in R-markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want to extract the example code from an `R` package and run it in an `rmarkdown` file automatically.

I am able to extract the code using the function `utils::example` as follows.

```
example("geom_histogram", package = "ggplot2", ask = F,
         prompt.prefix = "", give.lines = TRUE)[-(1:5)]
```

I have tried to use chunk options `results="asis"` as follows, but the result is given as code output rather than code chunk.

````
```{r,echo = FALSE, results="asis"}
cat("```{r}")
library(ggplot2)
cat(paste(example("geom_histogram", package = "ggplot2", ask = F,
                  prompt.prefix = "", give.lines = TRUE)[-(1:5)], collapse = "\n"))
cat("```")
```
````

I would like to have the code as a code block and the output from the same as in http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

You can create a function to extract code and use it as a `code` argument in chunk option.

```
# Function saved in functions.R file
getCode <- function(myFunction, myPackage) {
    example(myFunction, myPackage, ask = FALSE, character.only = TRUE,
            prompt.prefix = "", give.lines = TRUE)[-(1:5)]
}
```

Your `Rmd` (`myFile.Rmd`) should look like this:

> ````
> ```{r, meta, include = FALSE}
> myPackage  <- "ggplot2"
> myFunction <- "geom_histogram"
> source("functions.R")
> ```
>
> ```{r, intro, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
> cat("#", myPackage, "\n")
> cat("##", myFunction, "\n")
> library(myPackage, character.only = TRUE)
> ```
>
> ```{r, runCode, code = getCode(myFunction, myPackage)}
> ```
> ````

Knit `Rmd` with: `knitr::knit2html("myFile.Rmd")` for a result like this:

[image]

---

**Previous answer:**

Write extracted code to a dummy file (`foo.R`) and use it as a `code` argument in chunk option.

Example file (`myFile.Rmd`):

- First chunk: loads tested library
- Second chunk: extracts example and saves it to a file
- Third chunk: runs extracted code

> ````
> ```{r, meta, include = FALSE}
> library(ggplot2)
> ```
>
> ```{r, getCode, include = FALSE}
> code <- example("geom_histogram", package = "ggplot2", ask = FALSE,
>                 prompt.prefix = "", give.lines = TRUE)[-(1:5)]
> write.table(code, "foo.R", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
> ```
>
> ```{r, runCode, code = readLines("foo.R")}
> ```
> ````

knit file with `knitr::knit2html("myFile.Rmd")` for a result like this:

[image]

We can also remove hard-coded variables to have a more flexible output:

> ````
> ```{r, meta, include = FALSE}
> myPackage  <- "ggplot2"
> myFunction <- "geom_histogram"
> library(myPackage, character.only = TRUE)
> ```
>
> ```{r, getCode, include = FALSE}
> code <- example(myFunction, myPackage, ask = FALSE, character.only = TRUE,
>                 prompt.prefix = "", give.lines = TRUE)[-(1:5)]
> write.table(code, "foo.R", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
> ```
>
> ```{r, intro, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
> cat("#", myPackage, "\n")
> cat("##", myFunction, "\n")
> ```
>
> ```{r, runCode, code = readLines("foo.R")}
> ```
> ````